# User Defined Aggregates in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, aggregate-functions

I have a requirement in JasperReports: The user wants to dynamically select a set of columns, or a set of rows in the published report in the browser to calculate any aggregate like sum, count, etc (similar to Excel).

I am currently using Jaspersoft Studio and JasperReports Server v6.0.1. I cant find much help in my internet research and not sure if this is doable. Is this possible to achieve, If so can you please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate dynamic columns using crosstab element of jasper reports. You will then have to create list of data objects(JRDataSource).

In my case, all the aggregation was done on the server side and passed the value as a parameter using a hashmap .

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate a little bit more on this? Or provide a sample/link if possible for the same? Thanks!

Comment: ok, what I mean is, refer this example [dynamic parameter passing].http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530368/ireport-dynamic-parameter-passing-through-java. Similarly you can calculate all your agggregates and sum and pass it as a parameter.(Pname as in the example given). You will have to define it as <parameter name="Pname" class="java.lang.Integer"/> in jrxml and access it using $P{Pname}. You will have to define separate parameter values for every sum/aggregate